# Fill an array directly when creating a data set

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to fill an array when creating a new record in MongoDB. If I try that the first time, I don't get any errors, but the array is empty.
However, the second method (see below) works.
That means I first create the data object without the array, and then do an updateOne() on this object where I iterate over the array and enter the data. Surely that has to be easy?!

That's not how it works:

```
  const newHouse = await House({
  userId: req.body.userId,
  name: req.body.name,
  description: req.body.description,
  lat: req.body.lat,
  long: req.body.long,
  //Dosen't insert anything
  $push: {
    images: {
      $each: JSON.parse(req.body.images),
    },
  },
});
await newHouse.save();
```

This works:

```
  const newHouse = await House({
  userId: req.body.userId,
  name: req.body.name,
  description: req.body.description,
  lat: req.body.lat,
  long: req.body.long,
  images: [],
});

const saveHouse = await newHouse.save();
//Works
await saveHouse.updateOne({
  $push: {
    images: {
      $each: JSON.parse(req.body.images),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"mongoose": "^7.1.1"*

Passing the `$push` operator to the Model constructor is totally wrong. You can pass the value to the `images` field when instantiating the `House` model class. Mongoose will create the `images` sub-documents.

E.g.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { config } from '../../config';

const houseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  images: [{ url: String }],
});

const House = mongoose.model('house', houseSchema);

(async function main() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);

    const house = new House({
      name: 'house a',
      images: [{ url: 'http://example.com/avatar.jpg' }]
    })
    await house.save();

    // query
    const doc = await House.findOne({ name: 'house a' })
    console.log('doc: ', doc)


  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    await mongoose.connection.dropCollection('houses')
    await mongoose.connection.close()
  }
})();
```

Logs:

```bash
doc:  {
  _id: new ObjectId("6466119f7c5032ccad7962ef"),
  name: 'house a',
  images: [
    {
      url: 'http://example.com/avatar.jpg',
      _id: new ObjectId("6466119f7c5032ccad7962f0")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```